# How to remove a directory path from PATH permanently?

Tags: command-line, bash, paths

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am really new to Linux.

I created a `softwares` directory within the `Downloads` dir for all the software and added it to my PATH. Then I was advised that it's better to create a `bin` directory in your home, instead of keeping directories such as Downloads in the PATH. So, I did it. Now, my problem, I have both the directories in the PATH and some of my tools are not running due to this reason.

I did try some of the suggestions given in the posts here but it didn't work for me and since I am new, I am bit scared to experiment that I'll mess up every thing.

My PATH

```
$ echo $PATH 
/home/gjjha/bin:/home/gjjha/bin:/home/gjjha/bin:/home/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/ncbi-blast-2.5.0+/bin:/home/gjjha/bin:/home/gjjha/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin://home/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/ncbi-blast-2.5.0+:/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/ncbi-blast-2.5.0+/bin:/home/gjjha/home/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/ncbi-blast-2.5.0+/bin:/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/ncbi-blast-2.5.0+/bin:/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/ncbi-blast-2.5.0+/bin:/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/ncbi-blast-2.5.0+/bin:/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/bowtie2-2.2.9/index:/home/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/tophat-2.1.1:/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/bowtie2-2.2.9/index:/home/gjjha/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/bowtie2-2.2.9/index:/home/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/tophat-2.1.1:/home/gjjha/bin:/home/gjjha/bin/blastdb:/home/gjjha/bin/blast+2.5:/home/gjjha/blast+2.5/bin:/home/gjjha/blast+2.5/bin:/home/gjjha/bin/ncbi-blast-2.5.0+/bin
```

I want to remove the softwares dir and duplicates and want to keep `/home/gjjha/bin` since all softwares are in bin dir now.

Commands I tried:

```
PATH=echo $PATH | sed -e 's/:\/home\/wrong\/dir\/$//'
PATH= echo $PATH | sed -e 's/:/home/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/ncbi-blast-2.5.0+/bin/$//'
PATH=${PATH/%:/home/wrong/dir//}
PATH=${PATH%:/home/gjjha/Downloads/softwares//}
PATH=${PATH%:/home/gjjha/Downloads/softwares/ncbi-blast-2.5.0+/bin/}
```

I checked (even after rebooting), the softwares dir is still there.

Comment: Where did you set your path? You must have edited some config file.

Comment: Trying to edit variables on the fly with `sed` or parameter substitution is not the right way to approach this. Revert the changes you made then logout and login.

Comment: Please remove [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42746586/3776858) crossposting.

Comment: @Zanna         I have added the path using  vim .bashrc every time.

Comment: well you need to remove whatever you added to your `.bashrc` to set the PATH. Then it will be overidden by `/etc/environment` when you log out and back in. Then you can put the path you want in `.profile` (more appropriate than `.bashrc`)

Comment: How to remove paths from .bashrc?? that is my question

Comment: to replace your .bashrc with a clean one: `mv ~/.bashrc ~/bashrc-bak && cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` (that's all one command, ignore the break caused by the small size of the comment space)

Answer (score 3):

On my vanilla install of 16.04, the PATH variable is set from .profile for login shells

First save your current PATH  to a text file:

```
echo $PATH > currentpath.txt
```

I find it easiest to then open a new shell and do

```
sudo vi .profile
```

now edit or add the line to set the correct path

```
PATH="..."
```

with the path that you want inside the quotes.

The default path:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

(And it works from left to right - if an executable with the same name exists in `/usr/local/sbin` and `/usr/bin`, the version in `/usr/local/sbin` will be called when you type the name)

Press <kbd>esc</kbd> and **w**rite and **q**uit with

```
:wq
```

If you don't know **vi** you could use **nano** to edit the `.profile` file.  Might be easier.

Restart.

I did this so that my local bin folder was in the path for executables.  Dunno why it wasn't by default, but hey.